# migration from .net5 to .net6, view does not found

Tags: razor, .net-6.0

I have upgrade project to .net 6. On my localhost everything is fine, but on server doesn't work. Razor compiler no longer produces a Views assembly, it pruduces one dll file with .net6. I already install .net6 hosting bundle from [here](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet/6.0). But still not working.

```
InvalidOperationException: The view 'Login' was not found. The following locations were searched:
/Views/User/Login.cshtml
/Views/Shared/Login.cshtml
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewEngines.ViewEngineResult.EnsureSuccessful(IEnumerable<string> originalLocations)
```

**EDIT: I updated all of microsoft and system packages to latest version from nuget then publish is successful.**

Comment: Have you made any customization in program.cs or startup.cs ? Also personally I feel that community need more information in order to provide you solution.

Comment: Please show your publish settings.